# SUM function - NULL problem

Tags: sql, coldfusion, null, sum

I have a problem regarding to a SUM function in sql that gives NULLs, thus brakes all the structure of the table: (x-month,y-cities,value-Nettotal) but i get wrongly arranged values according to a y-cities, because there are no free spaces, i mean 0 values, here is the screenshot to make it more clear:

[image]

and the link to a question i asked before but couldnt get a clear answer: [group by cities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607421/group-by-cities)

So what I and Dave DuPlantis have wrote so far is:

**the query:**

```
<cfquery name="GET_SALES_TOTAL" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT SUM(COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0)) NETTOTAL,
           SC.CITY_ID,
           SC.CITY_NAME,
           M.INVOICE_MONTH
    FROM SETUP_CITY SC 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY C 
            ON SC.CITY_ID = C.CITY 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE I 
                    ON C.COMPANY_ID = I.COMPANY_ID
        , 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(MM,INVOICE_DATE) INVOICE_MONTH 
            FROM #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE
        ) M
    WHERE PURCHASE_SALES = 1 
    AND DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE) = M.INVOICE_MONTH 
    AND SC.COUNTRY_ID=1
    GROUP BY M.INVOICE_MONTH,
             SC.CITY_ID,
             SC.CITY_NAME
    ORDER BY M.INVOICE_MONTH,
             SC.CITY_ID,
             SC.CITY_NAME
</cfquery>
```

**and table:**

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" class="color-border">
    <tr class="color-header">
        <td class="txtbold" nowrap width="100">Aylar / Sehirler</td>
        <cfoutput query="GET_SALES_GRAND_TOTAL" group="city_id">
            <td class="txtbold">#city_name#</td>
        </cfoutput>
    </tr>
    <cfoutput query="GET_SALES_TOTAL" group="invoice_month"><!--- months first --->
        <tr class="color-row"><!--- month-specific stuff goes here --->
            <td class="txtbold">
                #invoice_month#                         
            </td>
            <cfoutput group="city_id"><!--- city-specific stuff --->
                <td>
                    #tlformat(nettotal,2)#<!--- format NETTOTAL however you want here --->
                </td>
            </cfoutput>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
</table>
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve this kind of problem?! Thank you everyone for help!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what problem you want solved - is it that you want values to appear as '0' in the grid in cells that are currently unpopulated? Also, if you try querying more than a year's worth of data, data from the same month for different years will appear in the same row. Additionally, which flavour of SQL (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLServer etc.) are you using?

Comment: @Mark yes i want values to appear as 0 on the grid in cells that are currently unpopualated, the year is not a problem, i will define it by myself, and i have a SQLServer 2008 R2 Enterprise

Comment: Looks like you are still doing an INNER JOIN. So the results do not always contain the same number of `months` for each `city`. That is why your output is uneven. For the `<cfoutput group..>` to work the query must contain the same number of months for each city. Possibly requiring sort of `cross join`. Have you tried using `pivot` instead?

Comment: @Leigh nope, don't know how to use it ^.^ can u give me an example?

Comment: @user775917 - Search on `ms sql pivot`. There are *tons* of examples, such as http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx or 
http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx Another option is to use a `cross join` so your results contain the same number of `month` records for each city. Then your cfoutput should work.

Comment: On a different point, `SUM(COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0))` returns the same as `SUM(NETTOTAL)`, i.e. you don't need `COALESCE` inside `SUM`. If you want to make sure that `SUM` doesn't return NULLs, apply `COALESCE` over `SUM`: `COALESCE(SUM(NETTOTAL,0))`.

Comment: Not exactly the "same". `SUM(NETOTAL)` may return null. Also, using `COALESCE` *before* the `SUM` prevents "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate ..." warnings in ms sql. Applying it after the fact has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leigh observes, you need the same number of months for each city for the output to populate as required - by linking invoice to sub-query M in the WHERE clause, you have turned it into an inner join. Amending the query to something like the following should work:

```
<cfquery name="GET_SALES_TOTAL" datasource="#dsn#">
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0)) NETTOTAL,
       SC.CITY_ID,
       SC.CITY_NAME,
       M.INVOICE_MONTH
FROM SETUP_CITY SC 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY C 
        ON SC.CITY_ID = C.CITY 
    CROSS JOIN  
    (   SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(MM,INVOICE_DATE) INVOICE_MONTH 
        FROM #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE
    ) M
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE I 
                ON C.COMPANY_ID = I.COMPANY_ID
               AND DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE) = M.INVOICE_MONTH 
WHERE PURCHASE_SALES = 1 
AND SC.COUNTRY_ID=1
GROUP BY M.INVOICE_MONTH,
         SC.CITY_ID,
         SC.CITY_NAME
ORDER BY M.INVOICE_MONTH,
         SC.CITY_ID,
         SC.CITY_NAME
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Yep. It may need to be tweaked further if `PURCHASE_SALES` belongs to the `INVOICE` table. I cannot tell from the original sql. @user775917 - `cross joins` are powerful, but they work by creating a cartesian product (ie lots of records). So be sure you understand them http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_join#Cross_join

Comment: @Mark thank you very much! but there is one remark, the purchase_sales belongs to invoice, thus should be placed in second LEFT OUTER JOIN, but, is it possible to erase the column, if all the rows values are zero?! because the list of cities now are not correctly arranged according to a values, i mean the list of cities is not full now, it is shorter than the list of values

Comment: @Mark here ist he screenshot, to make it more clear: http://s011.radikal.ru/i318/1108/9c/23c1af575337.jpg

Comment: @user775917 - You are using a totally different query to generate the headers ie `GET_SALES_GRAND_TOTAL`. Not a good idea unless you are *positive* they contain the same cities. Do they?

Comment: @Leigh now it is triple longer than values ))

Comment: @user775917 - Well .. just saying they do not match does not help us as we cannot *see* the raw results ;)

Comment: how can i count the sum for each city? and why does the list of names of cities, is longer?! here is the screenshot: http://i037.radikal.ru/1108/a4/00f6734a2523.jpg

Comment: That is not the *raw* results. We already know the report is wrong. We need to see the raw results to figure out why it is wrong. Post a dump of the results (and sql) for *both* queries. Without that information we can only guess ..

Comment: thank you guys for help, i managed the rest, the totals and city names, now everything works the way i wanted it to work :)