# sum COALESCE 0 instead of null

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

i cant add zero values instead of null, here is my sql:

```
 SELECT
                        S.STOCK_ID,
                        S.PRODUCT_NAME,
                        SUM(COALESCE(AMOUNT,0)) AMOUNT,
                        DATEPART(MM,INVOICE_DATE) AY
                    FROM
                        #DSN3_ALIAS#.STOCKS S
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN DAILY_PRODUCT_SALES DPS ON S.STOCK_ID = DPS.PRODUCT_ID
                    WHERE
                        MONTH(INVOICE_DATE) >= #attributes.startdate# AND 
                        MONTH(INVOICE_DATE) < #attributes.finishdate+1#
                    GROUP BY
                        DATEPART(MM,INVOICE_DATE),
                        S.STOCK_ID,
                        S.PRODUCT_NAME
                    ORDER BY
                        S.PRODUCT_NAME
```

and my table:

```
<cfoutput query="get_sales_total" group="stock_id">
                            <tr height="20" class="color-row">
                                <td>#product_name#</td>
                                <cfoutput group="ay"><td><cfif len(amount)>#amount#<cfelse>0</cfif></td></cfoutput>
                            </tr>
                        </cfoutput>
```

the result i want: [image]

and the result i get: [image]

thank you all for the help!

**+ EDIT :**

I have used the cross join technique, rewrote the sql:

```
SELECT
                        SUM(COALESCE(AMOUNT,0)) AMOUNT,S.STOCK_ID,S.PRODUCT_NAME,DPS.AY
                    FROM
                        #DSN3_ALIAS#.STOCKS S
                            CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT <cfif attributes.time_type eq 2>DATEPART(MM,INVOICE_DATE) AY<cfelse>DATEPART(DD,INVOICE_DATE) AY</cfif> 
                            FROM DAILY_PRODUCT_SALES) DPS
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN DAILY_PRODUCT_SALES DP ON S.STOCK_ID = DP.PRODUCT_ID AND 
                            <cfif attributes.time_type eq 2>DATEPART(MM,DP.INVOICE_DATE)<cfelse>DATEPART(DD,DP.INVOICE_DATE)</cfif> = DPS.AY
                    WHERE
                    <cfif attributes.time_type eq 2>
                        MONTH(INVOICE_DATE) >= #attributes.startdate# AND 
                        MONTH(INVOICE_DATE) < #attributes.finishdate+1#
                    <cfelse>
                        MONTH(INVOICE_DATE) = #attributes.startdate#
                    </cfif>
                    <cfif len(trim(attributes.product_cat)) and len(attributes.product_code)>
                        AND S.STOCK_CODE LIKE '#attributes.product_code#%'
                    </cfif>
                    GROUP BY DPS.AY,S.STOCK_ID,S.PRODUCT_NAME
                    ORDER BY DPS.AY,S.STOCK_ID,S.PRODUCT_NAME
```

and the result is: 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is because of the COALESCE? Looking at your diagram I don't think that the change in output is because the SUM(COALESCE (AMOUNT,0)) is returning NULL (which it shouldn't really do, anyway).

Comment: Don't you need to force the result set to have results for months where there were no quantities of that product sold? Seems to me you need to join against a dummy table perhaps?

Comment: robsoft, im sure, there is a sql problem, mb i need some how cross join em. but i don't know how exactly

Comment: rob, i asked like this question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022710/sum-function-null-problem , but still didnt understand very well, how to cross join or outer left join them so that the output for null result were the 0 value

Comment: 1) Which table contains the `INVOICE_DATE` column? 2) What is `attributes.startdate` - a month number or a date ?

Comment: leigh, invoice date is in dps and startdate is the number of month, from 1 to 12

Comment: @user775917, I've edited my initial answer to give you an example of how you might report a summary, with 'missing values', based on a table of orders and parts and report-dates. Dunno if it's clear enough for you to apply it to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE instead

SUM(CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE A END)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the database as Lasse suggested, or you can wrap each output value in a `Val` function, like so:

```
<cfoutput group="ay"><td>#Val(amount)#</td></cfoutput>
```

The `Val` function will convert any non-numeric value to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use ISNULL instead, ie;

```
 SUM(ISNULL(AMOUNT,0)) AMOUNT,
```

?

EDIT: okay, given that the problem seems to be missing values rather than nulls as such. try something like this.

First, create a permanent reporting_framework table. This one is based on months and years but you could extend it into days if you wished.

```
create table reporting_framework
([month] smallint, [year] smallint);
go

declare @year smallint;
declare @month smallint;

set @year=2000;
while @year<2500 
begin
  set @month=1;
  while @month<13
  begin
    insert into reporting_framework ([month], [year]) values (@month, @year);
    set @month=@month+1;
  end
  set @year=@year+1;
end

select * from reporting_framework;
```

(this gives you 6000 rows, from 2000 to 2499 - adjust to taste!)

Now we'll make a table of parts and a table of orders

```
create table parts
([part_num] integer, [description] varchar(100));
go

insert into parts (part_num, [description]) values (100, 'Widget');
insert into parts (part_num, [description]) values (101, 'Sprocket');
insert into parts (part_num, [description]) values (102, 'Gizmo');
insert into parts (part_num, [description]) values (103, 'Foobar');

create table orders
([id] integer, part_num integer, cost numeric(10,2), orderdate datetime);
go

insert into orders ([id], part_num, cost, orderdate) values
(1, 100, 49.99, '2011-10-30');
insert into orders ([id], part_num, cost, orderdate) values
(2, 101, 109.99, '2011-10-31');
insert into orders ([id], part_num, cost, orderdate) values
(3, 100, 47.99, '2011-10-31');
insert into orders ([id], part_num, cost, orderdate) values
(4, 102, 429.99, '2011-11-01');
insert into orders ([id], part_num, cost, orderdate) values
(5, 101, 111.17, '2011-11-01');
insert into orders ([id], part_num, cost, orderdate) values
(6, 101, 111.17, '2011-11-01');
insert into orders ([id], part_num, cost, orderdate) values
(7, 103, 21.00, '2011-09-15');
```

Now this is the table you base your query on, eg;

```
select rf.month, rf.year, p.description, sum(isnull(o.cost,0))
from reporting_framework rf cross join parts p
full outer join orders o 
on rf.year=year(o.orderdate) and rf.month=month(o.orderdate)
and p.part_num=o.part_num
where rf.year='2011'
group by p.description, rf.month, rf.year
order by rf.year, rf.month, p.description
```

Does this example help? There are probably loads of better ways of doing this (hello StackOverflow) but it might get you started thinking about what your problem is.
Not the CROSS JOIN to get all parts/dates combinations and then the FULL OUTER JOIN to get the orders into it.
The 'where' clause is just controlling your date range.

Comment: rob :) thank you very much, but im 100% sure there must be easier way to achieve the same effect using sql and coldfusion/html tables, and i need this solution, not the way you did it, sorry :)

Comment: @user775917 - Nothing hard about using a calendar table (it is a very common technique). It is either that or use the `cross join` technique posted in your previous question. Those are pretty much the only options.

Comment: @Leigh cross join technique, that is actually what im asking for, if i knew how to apply it, i would have applied it before :)

Comment: @user775917 - I see you edited your post. Is your `CROSS JOIN` working now? You really should consider using a (daily) calendar table for several reasons. First, populating it is a one time operation. Second, since you need a table of dates in multiple queries, having a calendar table will simplify your sql. Third, it usually improves performance. `DISTINCT` can be very slow when many records are involved. And using functions like `MONTH(..)` can prevent your database from utilizing indexes, making queries slower.

Comment: @user775917 - re: *Those are pretty much the only options* - Hm.. for some reason I thought you were using mySQL.. There is one additional option for MS SQL: using a CTE to generate a table of dates on the fly. But I would not recommend it in your case. I think you would reap greater benefits from using a calendar table instead.

Comment: @Leigh, thank you for explanation :) my cross join doesnt work, but i thinkk im somewhere near )) the other problem is that, i don't know how to apply this kind of calendar to my sql, i pretty sure it is a good solution, but stil if i could make it work :)

Comment: @user775917 - Do a search on calendar tables first. They are lots of articles on them. In short, it is just a table filled with individual dates (ie `dateColumn datetime`) for some range like Jan 14, 2000-Jan 1,2050. Once you create an populate it, it can be used in an `OUTER JOIN` to fill in the missing dates/months. After you read up on the concept, it will make a lot more sense to you :)